# Nothing happens when I try to integrate Gitkraken with Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys, gitkraken

I am new to Gitkraken and want to integrate with Gitlab.

When I go to Preferences -> Integrations -> Gitlab and click the "Connect to Gitlab", nothing happens. I expected a browser window to open, prompting me for my Gitlab credentials.

Notes:

- I have tried with Firefox and Google Chrome as my default browser
- the Gitkraken error log is empty
- the Gitkraken activity log contains:

```
    Request OAuth token from GitLab: started.
    Request OAuth token from GitLab: invalid token
    Request OAuth token from GitLab: finished with errors.
```

- Gitkraken outputs the following to stdout/stderr:

```
    (node:70656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid token
        at authenticateSaga (<embedded>:10:422633)
        at authenticateSaga.next (<anonymous>)
        at next (<embedded>:161:2671290)
        at currCb (<embedded>:161:2671915)
        at takeCb (<embedded>:161:2661241)
        at Object.put (<embedded>:161:2659312)
        at <embedded>:161:2675552
        at WebSocket.connection.onmessage (<embedded>:10:421538)
        at WebSocket.onMessage (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
        at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
        at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
        at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:834:20)
        at Receiver.emit (events.js:310:20)
        at Receiver.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
        at Receiver.dataMessage (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:437:14)
        at Receiver.getData (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:367:17)
    (node:70656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 9)
```

I am using Fedora 35 and have created a new SSH key in Gitkraken (but I assume it is not used until I have authenticated against Gitlab).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just in case, have you checked if connection is established to GitLab from your machine at all? Have you checked if other git clients can connect to GitLab from the machine? What is GitKraken version?

Comment: @BorisR It is version 8.1.1 of Gitkraken. Yes, I can sign in to Gitlab (in a browser) from this machine. How can I check if Gitkraken is establishing a connection to Gitlab?

Comment: Can you check if you can connect to other git sources from GitKraken (e.g. **Github**)?
Can you check if you can connect to Gitlab from other git clients?

Comment: I cannot connect to other sources, such as GitHub or BitBucket. I can connect to Gitlab using Sourcetree, however that is running the host Windows machine (Fedora35 is running as a VM on the Windows host)

Comment: 1. When you cannot connect to GitHub, BitBucket, do you see the same errors in Activity Log as when connecting to Gitlab?
2. Which VM engine are you using to launch Fedora?

Comment: @BorisR Thanks for your suggestions. The solution is to start gitkraken with the "--disable-software-rasterizer" option. The following now works for me: gitkraken --sandbox --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer.